# Installing mod_ssl on Centos, dependency issue

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, yum, mod-ssl

I'm installing a SSL certificate for a currently productive CentOS 5.8 (final)

So I runned this:

```
yum install mod_ssl
```

and got this:

```
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-65.el5.centos is needed by package 1:mod_ssl-2.2.3-65.el5.centos.x86_64
```

A few details about my instalation:

```
# yum list installed|grep httpd
httpd.x86_64                           2.2.20-1.w5                     installed
httpd-tools.x86_64                     2.2.20-1.w5                     installed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got `2.2.20-1.w5` installed, it is looking specifically for `2.2.3-65.el5` as shown by the `=`. It also seems that you have a nonstandard package installed - i.e. one that did not come out of the standard repos since all of the RH/CentOS packages end in `.elX` where X is the major version number.

To Answer the question in the comments. It appears that the `.w5` suffix is from the [Webtactic](http://www.webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/) repositories. If you don't need anything from that repo, I would suggest removing it's entry in `/etc/yum.repos.d` after removing the Apache install. If you do need things from that repo, I would suggest following their instructions at the bottom of the page I linked to above to disable the repo and only use it when needed.

There is no way to change the version of Apache that is installed without downtime, although if you backup the configs first it should be very minimal - on the order of 5 mins tops.

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it!

Comment: Thanks! So I guess my best option is to re-install `httpd` and it's dependencies using one of the standard repos. Correct me if I'm wrong, but that would be `yum remove httpd ...` and `yum install httpd ...`. Could you recommend "standard repo"?

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this without downtime?

Comment: @Mauro see my edit

Comment: Thanks Man. That's great. I didn't want to go through that delicate process so I've finally decided to get another instance from my cloud provider, replicate the server using the appropriate repos and linking the databases to the old server, fully test it. Then lock tables and migrate them. What do you think of this solution?

Comment: @Mauro Sounds like a very sound way to go about it.